# Read a line and convert to string in c

Tags: c

This is my first post here so dont really know how to post something here with correct format. I have a question on how to read a line from file and read some of the words as string and some as Int.

```
    int check = sscanf(read, "%s %d", string, &integer);
    printf("%s, %d", string, integer);
```

Above is kind of what I did. The input is "oneword 1". What I got is "(null) 4196448". So how can I do it correctly? Thank you

Here is part of my code.

```
    int i;
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
            char read[MAX_LENGTH_INPUT];
            fgets(read, sizeof(read), stdin);
            int check2 = sscanf(read, "%s %d", word, &number);
            printf("%s %d\n", word, number);
    }
```

So the for loop is to scan three lines in .in file. Can I do that?
Here is the .in file which is the input.

```
    oneword 1
    twoword 2
    thirdword 3
```

The output was

```
    (null) 4196448
    (null) 4196448
    (null) 4196448
```

Comment: `This is my first post here so dont really know how to post something here with correct format` You can learn from existing posts, and read through the _wealth_ of help material written just for people like you. Doesn't matter whether you're new. Welcome!

Comment: @terk: the format of your post is all right.

Comment: @terk: The formatting is OK, but you should try to produce a _minimal but complete program that still shows the same problem_. You have only shown part of the code, and it seems not even part of the real code, so we would have to _guess_ where the problem might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also in your code `int check2 = sscanf(read, "%s %d %d", word, &number);` format specifier are 3 but arguments 2.

if `file` contain data like

```
oneword 1
secondword 2
thirdword 3
fourthword 4
```

Then

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("file", "r");
    char read[100];
    int integer;
    char string[64];
    while (fgets(read, sizeof(read), fp) != NULL) 
    {
        int check = sscanf(read, "%s %d", string, &integer);
        if (check == 2) {
             printf("%s, %d\n", string, integer);
         }
         else{
             printf("Failed to scan all values\n");
         }
    }
}
```

And output is

```
oneword, 1
secondword, 2
thirdword, 3
fourthword, 4
```

You can modify `fgets` here to take input from `stdin` by just replacing `fp` by `stdin` in line `while (fgets(read, sizeof(read), fp) != NULL)`

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty much the same as your code except I don't open a file. Sorry I was trying to not make it like a homework so I'm making it simple. It is actually a .in file which contains the input like what you mentioned. So this is what I did to read the line and after that the code in my question.    
    fgets(read, sizeof(read), stdin);
    int check = sscanf(read, "%s %d", string, &integer);
    printf("%s, %d", string, integer);

Comment: @terk it's always best to post your exact code, rather than posting bits of it and describing the rest :)

Comment: @terk Ok..so you can check for `stdin`.And also your subject line `Read a line from file and convert to string in c` confuse everyone because if you don't deal with `file` then not require to mention here.

Comment: It would be even better to use the `check` return value (which should be `const`, too) to verify that `sscanf()` succeeded.

Comment: @Jayesh yeah it should be 2 arguments. I have edited the question. Can you check what is wrong?

Comment: @terk I am not getting you exactly on one hand you say that data in `.in` file but on another hand in `fgets` you used `stdin`. confusing..

Comment: @Jayesh the .in file contains the input, I guess I can use stdin, right?. I managed to print the correct output if all arguments in the .in file are integer. But if the input in the file is word, I got null.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `sscanf`

which reads data from `char *` type and stores them according to parameter format into the locations given by the additional arguments, as if `scanf` was used, but reading from string instead of the standard input (stdin).

you need to use `fscanf` and `read` in your code should be pointer to a FILE.

Comment: Seems like you want make use of `sscanf`, why don't you paste the rest of the code, so that we can see whats wrong, read in your code should be char * or char [] and should contain the value "oneword 1".